# Error while creating authenticating using node.js and express.js

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, frontend, backend

So I am creating e-commerce website where I am creating a authentication program for seller using express and node. I am able to create user and get user details on login while using postman to verify the API's are working.
But, when I try to call the API in my react frontend and to get user details while logging in and redirect the user to main page, the user is not getting directed and I am getting a '?' in front of my URL in the address bar

The backend API code :-

```js
const loginExistingSeller = asyncHandler( async(req, res) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body
    try{
        const userDetails = await sellerAuthModel.findOne({ username: username })
        
        if (userDetails.password === password ){
            res.send(userDetails)
        }
        else {
            res.send('Email or Password is wrong')
        }
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log('Error in Fetching details')
    }
})
```

API ROUTE : `sellerAuthRouter.post('/login', sellerAuthController.loginExistingSeller)`

The frontend code :-
API call:-

```js
const existingUserDetails = async(username, password) => {
    try{
        const response = await fetch(`${baseURL}/sellerAuth/login`, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                username: username,
                password: password
            }),
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
            }
        })
        const data = await response.json()
        return data
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

REACT COMPONENT:-

```js
import '../styles/sellerLogin.css'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { existingUserDetails } from '../../utils/sellerAPI'

function SellerLoginPage() {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState([])
    const navigate = useNavigate()

    const loginFunction = async() => {
        try{
            let response = await existingUserDetails(username, password)
            setUserDetails(response)
            console.log(userDetails)
            navigationFunction('/sellerDashboard')
        }
        catch(err) {
            console.log('User not found')
        }
    }

    const navigationFunction = (page) => {
        navigate(page)
    }

    return (
        <>
        <div className='seller-container'>
            <div className="seller-login-page">
                <div className="seller-form">
                    <form className="seller-login-form">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="username" value={username} onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}/>
                        <input type="password" placeholder="password" value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
                        <button onClick={() => loginFunction()}>login</button>
                        <p className="message">Not registered? <a onClick={() => navigationFunction('/sellerSignup')}>Create an account</a></p>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default SellerLoginPage
```

I am expecting it to redirect to the Main Dashboard.

Comment: So what is the output you are getting from your API call from your frontend. Maybe if we are able to see what your server is returning, we can narrow down on the issue

Comment: And also i am requesting you to send out a detailed response status and a detailed message from your server using ```.status(xxx)``` and a JSON body with error text if needed from the express backend

Comment: What is the error (detailed) you are getting?

Comment: its solved, the form was submitting the response in its default way so i just added the function to prevent that